# Using karate-config parameters in a feature file

Tags: karate

The karate [header examples](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/headers/headers.feature) do not show how to access config values other than `baseUrl`. When I switch environments (passing in `-Dkarate.env=qual` as part of the run command) then `baseUrl` is set correctly.

The problem is, I want to use other config values [as shown here](https://github.com/intuit/karate#configuration) but when I run the test, it fails to access `config.ApiKey` correctly. Instead I get this error

```
html report:
file:/C:/bitbucket/karate-checkdigit-api/target/surefire-reports/TEST-features.checkdigitapi.VA.html
Tests run: 250, Failures: 0, Errors: 50, Skipped: 175, Time elapsed: 4.112 sec <<< FAILURE!
* def secretKey = config.apiKey(| XYZ | 2110974841 | 204 | Valid |)  Time elapsed: 0.005 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: no variable found with name: config
at com.intuit.karate.Script.getValuebyName(Script.java:323)
at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalJsonPathOnVarByName(Script.java:378)
at com.intuit.karate.Script.eval(Script.java:309)
at com.intuit.karate.Script.eval(Script.java:194)
at com.intuit.karate.Script.assign(Script.java:656)
at com.intuit.karate.Script.assign(Script.java:587)
at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.def(StepDefs.java:265)
at ✽.* def secretKey = config.apiKey(features/checkdigitapi/XYZ.feature:6)
```

My `.feature` file and `karate-config.js` are below.

#### XYZ.feature

```gherkin
@regression
Feature: Checkdigit Algorithm API

Background:
* url baseUrl
* def secretKey = config.apiKey
* configure ssl = true

Scenario Outline: Testing XYZ algorithm

* configure headers = { KeyId: secretKey, Accept: 'application/json' }
Given path 'headers'
And param url = baseUrl
And params { customerId: '<custcode>', algoId: '<algo>' }
When method get
Then status <val>

Examples:
  | algo   | custcode      | val   | comment |
  | XYZ    | 2110974841    | 204   | Valid |
  | XYZ    | 7790011614    | 204   | Valid |
  | XYZ    | 5580015174    | 204   | Valid |
  | XYZ    | 2110974840    | 400   | expected check digit 1 |
  | XYZ    | 211097484     | 400   | not 10 digits |
  | XYZ    | 211097484x    | 400   | not numeric |
```

#### karate-config.js

```js
function() {    
  //set up runtime variables based on environment
  //get system property 'karate.env'
  var env = karate.env;
  if (!env) { env = 'dev'; }  // default when karate.env not set

  // base config
  var config = {
    env: env,
    baseUrl: 'https://localapi.abc123.example.com/api/v1/validate/customerid',
    apiKey: ''
  }
  //switch environment
  if (env == 'dev') {
  config.baseUrl = 'https://devapi.abc123.example.com/api/v1/validate/customerid';
  config.apiKey  = 'fake-1ba403ca8938176f3a62de6d30cfb8e';
  } 
  else if (env == 'qual') { //Pre-production environment settings
  config.baseUrl = 'https://qualapi.abc123.example.com/api/v1/validate/customerid';
  config.apiKey  = 'fake-d5de2eb8c0920537f5488f6535c139f2';
  }

  karate.log('karate.env =', karate.env);
  karate.log('config.baseUrl =', config.baseUrl);
  karate.log('config.apiKey =', config.apiKey);

  return config;
}
```

(similar issue here, using a separate `headers.js`: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/94)

Comment: Similar question here, but not quite applicable to my use case: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46299245/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Keep in mind that all the keys **within** the JSON object returned by `karate-config.js` will be injected as variables, and nothing else. So you will not be able to refer to `config`, but you will certainly be able to refer to `apiKey`.

I think if you make this simple change, things will start working:

```
* def secretKey = apiKey
```

Also, I think you have a problem in the first line of the scenario, it should be:

```
* configure headers = { KeyId: '#(secretKey)', Accept: 'application/json' }
```

Comment: Thank you for the amazingly prompt reply

Comment: It works! I've been using karate with maven & intellij IDEA, and it's such a relief not to write glue code for everything.

Comment: @ropata glad to hear that ! do spread the word :) sounds like you have used cucumber in anger before, you may find this an interesting read: https://hackernoon.com/yes-karate-is-not-true-bdd-698bf4a9be39

Comment: Could you please add this to the main readme in the intuit/karate github?

Comment: hey @PeterThomas 
what is the difference between
`KeyId: secretKey,`
and
`KeyId: '#(secretKey)'` ?
is it possible to use **apiKey** with out assigning to def inside of the message?
like 
`* print "Key in this project is #apiKey"  `

Thank you

Comment: @SaidYusifli read the docs (yet again :) and ask a specific question if needed: https://github.com/intuit/karate#rules-for-embedded-expressions

Comment: @PeterThomas i am doing my best, reading and trying to understand. even how you see i am using stackoverflow to find answers... but will really appreciate if you can just answer to previous question. this project is new for me and its really big. i am trying to learn everything but sometimes need tips like in this situation :) Thank you for this project Peter.

Comment: @SaidYusifli ask a new question please

Answer (score 2):

FYI my final, correctly working `XYZ.feature` file looks like this now.
The line `Given path 'headers'` caused header info to creep into the url so it's removed.

#### XYZ.feature

```gherkin
@regression
Feature: Checkdigit Algorithm API

Background:
* url baseUrl
* def secretKey = apiKey
* configure ssl = true

Scenario Outline: Testing XYZ algorithm
* configure headers = { KeyId: '#(secretKey)', Accept: 'application/json' }
Given url baseUrl
And params { customerId: '<custcode>', algoId: '<algo>' }
When method get
Then status <val>

Examples:
[...]
```