# what is the difference between `KeyId: secretKey` and `KeyId: '#(secretKey)'`?

Tags: karate

i have a question regarding to this ticket
[Using karate-config parameters in a feature file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47445984/using-karate-config-parameters-in-a-feature-file/47446662?noredirect=1#comment106676035_47446662)

what is the difference between 
`KeyId: secretKey`, 
and 
`KeyId: '#(secretKey)'` ? 
is it possible to use apiKey with out assigning to def inside of the message? like 
`* print "Key in this project is #apiKey"` 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked 3 questions:

a) Please read: https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-expressions

b) Please read: https://github.com/intuit/karate#embedded-expressions

c) Please read: https://github.com/intuit/karate#print

for example:

```
* def val = 'bar'
# correct
* def temp = { foo: '#(val)' } 
# wrong
* def temp = { foo: val }
# correct but not recommended
* def temp = ({ foo: val })
# variables are easy to use, forget about the # part
* print 'value of val:', val
```

Comment: I have variable cardholder in my karate-config file. i saved it under entrID. now how can i provide it to my json RequestBody ENTR_ID ? i am a little bit confused in this part.. * def entrID = cardholder * def requestContactHistoryAdd = """ { "Endpoint": "ContactHistoryAdd", "RequestBody": "{ \"ENTR_ID\" : \"entrID\", \"BHVR_ID\" : \"VRU\", }" } """

Comment: here is the screenshot https://imgur.com/LX5x5Wg
just make question more clear

Thank you :)

Comment: @SaidYusifli ask new question