# Set url for all features

Tags: configuration, karate

My question looks a lot like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46299245/how-to-get-a-value-ex-baseurl-in-every-karate-feature) but the accepted answer does not correspond to my target usage :

I would like to set `url` once and for all in an `initialize.feature` file, and never set it again afterwards. In other words I don't want to clutter every single feature files with the same following statement :

```
* url baseUrl
```

My `baseUrl` value is set based on `karate.env`, e.g. `https://localhost` for `local` environment and `http://prod.env.com` for `prod`. It does not change.

`path` will change in our feature files because we test different endpoints.

I tried the following setup :

- in `karate-config.js` :

```
config.baseUrl = 'https://localhost';
// ... code changing config.baseUrl based on karate.env == 'prod' or not
var result = karate.callSingle('classpath:utility/initialize.feature', config);
```

- in `initialize.feature` :

```
@ignore
Feature:

  Scenario: Initialize
      * print baseUrl
      * url baseUrl
```

We can see that `baseUrl` is correctly printed when executing `initialize.feature` file.

But in any executed feature afterwards, I get the following error :

```
some-test.feature:24 - url not set, please refer to the keyword documentation for 'url'
```

Is it possible to set `url` only in my `initialize.feature` file, and never afterwards ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. You will have to do `* url baseUrl` at least *once* in every feature file. There are multiple reasons for this - readability and maintainability for one, and if you look at the ["hello world example"](https://gist.github.com/ptrthomas/d5a2d9e15d0b07e4f1b46f692a599f93) - note how you could omit the `url` in the second call because you are following the REST-ful patterns.

Since you can do `* url baseUrl` in the `Background:` and have all other `Scenario`-s inherit - this is normally ok in practice, and in real-life API testing we see that you do need to switch URL-s within a test (e.g. for auth). If you feel very strongly about this - you could consider a pull-request. FWIW this is the first time in 2.5 years that someone has ever requested this.

Comment: Ok I see, thanks. It seemed natural to me that we should be able to factorize common things as we can do in programming in general.

Comment: @SimonBudin Karate uses a "builder pattern" behind the scenes. there are a few things you "set" before you "fire" an HTTP request. the `url` is just one of them. and I already mentioned you can do the `url` once per feature in the `Background`.